# Writing $A=B+C$ where $B$ is diagonable, $C$ is nilpotent and $BC = CB$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help with exercise 4 in section 57 of Paul Halmos' *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*:

> If $A$ is a linear transformation (on a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field), then there exist linear transformation $B$ and $C$ such that $A = B + C$, $B$ is diagonable, $C$ is nilpotent, and $BC = CB$; the transformations $B$ and $C$ are uniquely determined by these conditions.

My thoughts:

Let $T = X^{-1}AX$ such that $T$ is "triangular". Then $T = D + N$, where $D$ is a diagonable and $N$ is nilpotent and $A = XTX^{-1} = XDX^{-1} + XNX^{-1}$.

Comment: That's not an exercise, that's the Jordan Normal Form Theorem

Comment: Nope. This is more subtle than that. Your $D$ and $D$ will not necessarily commute. The key word is: Dunford decomposition.

@Hagen: Jordan form is an overkill. Dhnford decomposition is way easier to establish.

Comment: What do you mean by 'diagonable'? Is it 'diagonal' or 'diagonalizable'?

Comment: Seconding @HagenvonEitzen's comment. This is like assigning the van-kampen theorem as an exercise. In principle you can do it with enough guidance, but it is a fundamental theorem of the subject and should probably be explained in full at some point, not left as an exercise.